# HTTP Error 400 Bad Request (Other similar questions aren't helping me)

Tags: python, google-api, google-api-python-client

None of the other similarly names questions have solved my problem.

Why am I getting this error? I copied and pasted this example code from google's github.

```
import pprint

from googleapiclient.discovery import build

def main():
  # Build a service object for interacting with the API. Visit
  # the Google APIs Console <http://code.google.com/apis/console>
  # to get an API key for your own application.
  service = build("customsearch", "v1",
        developerKey="AIzaSyDRRpR3GS1F1_jKNNM9HCNd2wJQyPG3oN0")

  res = service.cse().list(
      q='lectures',
      cx='017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve',
    ).execute()
  pprint.pprint(res)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[Here is where I go the code from](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/blob/master/samples/customsearch/main.py)

I am getting this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testpython", line 17, in <module>
    main()
  File "testpython", line 12, in main
    cx='017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve',
  File "/home/mddrill/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/util.py", line 137, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mddrill/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 838, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=lectures&alt=json&cx=017576662512468239146%3Aomuauf_lfve&key=AIzaSyDRRpR3GS1F1_jKNNM9HCNd2wJQyPG3oN0 returned "Bad Request">
```

Comment: Is that really your key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to access that [bad URL](https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=lectures&alt=json&cx=017576662512468239146%3Aomuauf_lfve&key=AIzaSyDRRpR3GS1F1_jKNNM9HCNd2wJQyPG3oN0) and is says that the reason is "keyExpired". Also the code you put here includes the following documentation:

> Visit the Google APIs Console http://code.google.com/apis/console to
>   get an API key for your own application.

Try doing as it says. Good luck!